# передача значения из одного input в другой

Tags: javascript

у меня есть такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
    <button onmousemove="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
    <button ondblclick="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red" onmouseout="alert('hi')">наведи на меня а потом убери</div><br><br>

        <input type="text" value="ку-ку" id="inp">
        <button onclick="buttClickInputOne();">hi</button><br><br>
        <input type="text" value="ку-ку" id="inpa">
        <button onclick="buttClickInputTwo();">hi</button><br><br>

<div>

<img src="../photo2.jpg" alt="" id="phoTwo" width="200px" height="200px">
<img src="../photo3.jpg" alt="" id="phoThr" width="200px" height="200px">
<button onclick="changePhotoClick()">click</button>
</div>

<input type="text" id="input_While" onclick="inputWhileTrue()" value="click on me"><br><br>

<input type="text" id="inputChangeOne" onclick="inputChangeOne()" value="click on me"><br><br>

<input type="text" id="inputChangeTwo" onclick="inputChangeTwo()" value="click on me"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" id="submitOne" onclick="submitOne()"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" id="submitTwo" onclick="submitTwo()">


<div>

        <img src="../photo2.jpg" alt="" id="phoTwoFst" width="200px" height="200px" onmousemove="changePhotoOn()">
        <img src="../photo3.jpg" alt="" id="phoThrSec" width="200px" height="200px" onmouseout="changePhotoOut()">
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="inputChangeColor"  value="click on me">
        <button onclick="inputChangeColor()">click</button><br><br>

        <input type="text" id="inputClose/Open"  value="click on me">
        <button onclick="inputClose()">click</button>
        <button onclick="inputOpen()">click</button><br><br>

        <input type="text" id="inputCss"  value="click on me">
        <button onclick="inputCss()">click</button><br><br>

        <input type="submit" id="submitBlock" onclick="submitBlock()" value="click on me"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitUnblock" onclick="submitUnblock()" value="click on me"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" id="submitClick" onclick="submitClick()" value="click on me"><br><br>

        <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100px;">

        <input type="text" id="inputMove"  value="click on me" style="position: absolute;">
        <button onclick="inputMove()" style="position: absolute; left: 200px;" id="submitMove">click</button><br><br>
            </div>
        <input type="text" id="inputCsss"  value="click on me" style="position: absolute;">
        <button onclick="inputCsss()" style="position: absolute; left: 200px;" id="submitCsss">click</button><br><br>

        <input type="text" id="inputChangeTwoFst"  value="click me" ><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="inputChangeTwoSec"  value="click on me" >
        <button onclick="inputChangeTwo()" id="submitChangeTwo">click</button><br><br>







    <script>

        function inputChangeTwo(){
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoFst");
            var m = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoSec");
            var n = m.value;
            var v = a.value;
            m.value = v;
            a.value = n;
        }

        function inputCsss(){
            var a =document.getElementById("inputCsss");
            a.value = "my css: www eee aaa";
        }

        function inputMove() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inputMove")
            var w = document.getElementById("submitMove")
            a.style.right ="5px";
            w.style.left ="5px";

        }

        function submitClick() {
            var a = document.getElementById("submitClick");
            aaa++;
            a.value = aaa;
        }

        function submitBlock() {
            var a = document.getElementById("submitBlock");
            a.disabled = true;
            aa.style.display = "inline";

        }

        function submitUnblock() {
            var a = document.getElementById("submitBlock");
            a.disabled = false;
            aa.style.display = "none";

        }

        function inputCss(){
            var a =  document.getElementById("inputCss");
            a.style.border = "0px solid white";
            a.value = "css";

        }

        function inputClose() {
            var a =  document.getElementById("inputClose/Open");
            a.hidden = true;
        }

        function inputOpen() {
            var a =  document.getElementById("inputClose/Open");
            a.hidden = false;
        }

        function inputChangeColor(){
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeColor");
            a.style.color= "red";


        }

                        function changePhotoOut(){
            var a = document.getElementById("phoTwoFst");
            a.style.display = "block";
            c.style.display = "none";

}  

                function changePhotoOn(){
            var a = document.getElementById("phoTwoFst");
            a.style.display = "none";
            c.style.display = "block";

}  

                function submitTwo() {
            var a = document.getElementById("submitTwo");
            a.disabled = true;
            a.value = "nnnn";
        }

        function submitOne() {
            var a = document.getElementById("submitOne");
            a.value = "nnnn";
        }
                function inputChangeOne() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeOne");
           a.value = "i changed my text";
        }

        function inputChangeTwo() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwo");
            number++;
            if (number == 1){
                a.value = "i changed my text";
            }else if(number == 2){
                a.value = "i changed my text again";
            }else{
                number = 0;
            }
        }


        function inputWhileTrue () {
            var inputWhile = document.getElementById("input_While");
            while(true){
                alert(this.value);
            }
        }
        function buttClickInputOne() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inp");
            alert(a.value);
        }

        function buttClickInputTwo() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inpa");
            a.value = "asdf";
        }
        function changePhotoClick(){
            var a = document.getElementById("phoTwo");
            a.style.display = "none";
            b.style.display = "block";

}  
var b = document.getElementById("phoThr");

b.style.display = "none";

var c = document.getElementById("phoThrSec");

c.style.display = "none";

let number = 0;

let aa = document.getElementById("submitUnblock");
aa.style.display="none";

let aaa = 0;
</script>
```

этот код должен из первого `input` переводить `value` во второй `input` и тоже самое со вторым `input`, но у меня не хочет переводиться я уже 3 часа мучаюсь и не могу решить эту задачу

Comment: ето похоже ошибка копирования в коде закрыто

Comment: Так он работает. Может вы в JsFiddle писали код? Там не работают on-события внутри HTML )

Comment: не знаю у меня не работал я делал в VSCode

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, всю страницу с кодом целиком. Потому что указанный вами код работает, и проблема где-то в другом месте, видимо. У вас функция обернута в <script></script>?

Comment: у меня есть задачки и я просто все их делал в одном файле

Comment: переименуйте функцию `inputChangeTwo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки: **повторное использование названия функции** `inputChangeTwo`.

```
function inputChangeTwo(){
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoFst");
            var m = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoSec");
            var n = m.value;
            var v = a.value;
            m.value = v;
            a.value = n;
        }
```

и

```
function inputChangeTwo() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwo");
            number++;
            if (number == 1){
                a.value = "i changed my text";
            }else if(number == 2){
                a.value = "i changed my text again";
            }else{
                number = 0;
            }
        }
```

Пример с переименованной функцией

```js
function inputChangeTwoOther(){
                var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoFst");
                var m = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwoSec");
                var n = m.value;
                var v = a.value;
                m.value = v;
                a.value = n;
            }
    
            function inputCsss(){
                var a =document.getElementById("inputCsss");
                a.value = "my css: www eee aaa";
            }
    
            function inputMove() {
                var a = document.getElementById("inputMove")
                var w = document.getElementById("submitMove")
                a.style.right ="5px";
                w.style.left ="5px";
    
            }
    
            function submitClick() {
                var a = document.getElementById("submitClick");
                aaa++;
                a.value = aaa;
            }
    
            function submitBlock() {
                var a = document.getElementById("submitBlock");
                a.disabled = true;
                aa.style.display = "inline";
    
            }
    
            function submitUnblock() {
                var a = document.getElementById("submitBlock");
                a.disabled = false;
                aa.style.display = "none";
    
            }
    
            function inputCss(){
                var a =  document.getElementById("inputCss");
                a.style.border = "0px solid white";
                a.value = "css";
    
            }
    
            function inputClose() {
                var a =  document.getElementById("inputClose/Open");
                a.hidden = true;
            }
    
            function inputOpen() {
                var a =  document.getElementById("inputClose/Open");
                a.hidden = false;
            }
    
            function inputChangeColor(){
                var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeColor");
                a.style.color= "red";
    
    
            }
    
                            function changePhotoOut(){
                var a = document.getElementById("phoTwoFst");
                a.style.display = "block";
                c.style.display = "none";
                    
    }  
    
                    function changePhotoOn(){
                var a = document.getElementById("phoTwoFst");
                a.style.display = "none";
                c.style.display = "block";
                    
    }  
    
                    function submitTwo() {
                var a = document.getElementById("submitTwo");
                a.disabled = true;
                a.value = "nnnn";
            }
    
            function submitOne() {
                var a = document.getElementById("submitOne");
                a.value = "nnnn";
            }
                    function inputChangeOne() {
                var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeOne");
               a.value = "i changed my text";
            }
    
            function inputChangeTwo() {
                var a = document.getElementById("inputChangeTwo");
                number++;
                if (number == 1){
                    a.value = "i changed my text";
                }else if(number == 2){
                    a.value = "i changed my text again";
                }else{
                    number = 0;
                }
            }
    
    
            function inputWhileTrue () {
                var inputWhile = document.getElementById("input_While");
                while(true){
                    alert(this.value);
                }
            }
            function buttClickInputOne() {
                var a = document.getElementById("inp");
                alert(a.value);
            }
        
            function buttClickInputTwo() {
                var a = document.getElementById("inpa");
                a.value = "asdf";
            }
            function changePhotoClick(){
                var a = document.getElementById("phoTwo");
                a.style.display = "none";
                b.style.display = "block";
                
    }  
    var b = document.getElementById("phoThr");
    
    b.style.display = "none";
    
    var c = document.getElementById("phoThrSec");
    
    c.style.display = "none";
    
    let number = 0;
    
    let aa = document.getElementById("submitUnblock");
    aa.style.display="none";
    
    let aaa = 0;
```

```html
у меня есть такой код:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
        <button onmousemove="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
        <button ondblclick="alert('hi')">hi</button><br><br>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red" onmouseout="alert('hi')">наведи на меня а потом убери</div><br><br>
    
            <input type="text" value="ку-ку" id="inp">
            <button onclick="buttClickInputOne();">hi</button><br><br>
            <input type="text" value="ку-ку" id="inpa">
            <button onclick="buttClickInputTwo();">hi</button><br><br>
    
    <div>
    
    <img src="../photo2.jpg" alt="" id="phoTwo" width="200px" height="200px">
    <img src="../photo3.jpg" alt="" id="phoThr" width="200px" height="200px">
    <button onclick="changePhotoClick()">click</button>
    </div>
    
    <input type="text" id="input_While" onclick="inputWhileTrue()" value="click on me"><br><br>
    
    <input type="text" id="inputChangeOne" onclick="inputChangeOne()" value="click on me"><br><br>
    
    <input type="text" id="inputChangeTwo" onclick="inputChangeTwo()" value="click on me"><br><br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" id="submitOne" onclick="submitOne()"><br><br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" id="submitTwo" onclick="submitTwo()">
    
    
    <div>
    
            <img src="../photo2.jpg" alt="" id="phoTwoFst" width="200px" height="200px" onmousemove="changePhotoOn()">
            <img src="../photo3.jpg" alt="" id="phoThrSec" width="200px" height="200px" onmouseout="changePhotoOut()">
            </div>
    
            <input type="text" id="inputChangeColor"  value="click on me">
            <button onclick="inputChangeColor()">click</button><br><br>
    
            <input type="text" id="inputClose/Open"  value="click on me">
            <button onclick="inputClose()">click</button>
            <button onclick="inputOpen()">click</button><br><br>
    
            <input type="text" id="inputCss"  value="click on me">
            <button onclick="inputCss()">click</button><br><br>
    
            <input type="submit" id="submitBlock" onclick="submitBlock()" value="click on me"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submitUnblock" onclick="submitUnblock()" value="click on me"><br><br>
            
            <input type="submit" id="submitClick" onclick="submitClick()" value="click on me"><br><br>
    
            <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100px;">
    
            <input type="text" id="inputMove"  value="click on me" style="position: absolute;">
            <button onclick="inputMove()" style="position: absolute; left: 200px;" id="submitMove">click</button><br><br>
                </div>
            <input type="text" id="inputCsss"  value="click on me" style="position: absolute;">
            <button onclick="inputCsss()" style="position: absolute; left: 200px;" id="submitCsss">click</button><br><br>
    
            <input type="text" id="inputChangeTwoFst"  value="click me" ><br><br>
            <input type="text" id="inputChangeTwoSec"  value="click on me" >
            <button onclick="inputChangeTwoOther()" id="inputChangeTwoOther">click</button><br><br>
    
  


</body>
</html>
```